# Query syntax error in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query and it's giving SQL manual syntax error in MySql.

```
select 
count(case when v.created_at = vv.minva then user_id) as num_new_users
from bills v 
join (select user_id, min(created_at) as minva from bills t group by user_id ) vv 
on v.user_id = vv.user_id
```

Can someone please help me with the problem?

Comment: The case is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case statement` should be ended with `end`

```
select 
count(case when v.created_at = vv.minva then user_id end ) as num_new_users
from bills v 
join (select user_id, min(created_at) as minva from bills t group by user_id ) vv 
on v.user_id = vv.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use `end` in [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement.

```
select 
count(case when v.created_at = vv.minva then user_id end) as num_new_users
from bills v 
join (select user_id, min(created_at) as minva from bills t group by user_id ) vv 
on v.user_id = vv.user_id
```